# Integrate remote sensing & GIS data in a CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I am trying to develop a CNN model that takes as input a set of parameters derived from satellite imagery.

What are the necessary steps to go through in order to make the Geotiff data acceptable as a valid input for a keras model?

Comment: Which library do you plan to use for CNN ?   Libraries differ on how they combine image data with other features.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using keras on top of Tensorflow. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras functional API can be used to create models with multiple inputs (E.g. : Image, Categorical and Numerical).

From Geotiff, you can extract :

1. TIFF
2. CSV with other features

TIFF will be an input to stack of CNN layers and other features will feed dense layers. Output from both of these is combined in a dense layer.

[image]

Example : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/